# python скрипт не запускается через командную строку

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, скрипт

Я написал скрипт на питоне

```
from docx import Document
from os import listdir, remove
import os


def size(parag):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: x != ' ', parag.text)))


sz = 0

count_file = 1
directory = 'untitled folder 3'
files = listdir(directory)
full_directory = os.path.abspath('script-python-1.2')
document = Document()

for i in files:
    print(i)
    doc2 = Document(directory + '/' + i)
    for j in doc2.paragraphs:
        sz += size(j)
        document.add_paragraph(j.text)
        if sz > 26 * 10 ** 5:
            document.save(str(count_file) + '.docx')
            document = Document()
            sz = 0
            count_file += 1
    remove(directory + '/' + i)
```

Скрипт запускается и корректно работает через Pycharm но не запускается через командную строку. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: что означает фраза " не запускается через командную строку"? У меня точно такой же скрипт, и он запускается.

Comment: Может, Вы покажете, как запускаете?

Comment: Стопудов, у вас активная директория в консоли не та, где ваш скрипт находится, поэтому папка `directory` не была найдена и `listdir(directory)` ничего не нашел. Нужно в консоли через `cd` перейти в вашу папку. Либо дописать скрипт чтобы он путь до папки строил от текущей папки, где скрипт находится